# "As important as" or "As importantly as"

Tags: adjectives, word-difference, as, comparative-constructions

I found a sentence in The Hindu (*"[The Two Faces of Mr. Modi](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-opinion/the-two-faces-of-mr-modi/article6554177.ece)"*)

> As important as all the other qualities, we also expect rationality.

I think this sentence is not correct. It must be "importantly", instead of "important". Am I right? Or the version in the quoted sentence is also correct?

Answer (score 2):

> As important as all the other qualities, we also expect rationality.

The sentence could be rephrased as

> 1. We also expect rationality, a quality as **important** as all the others.
>      or, as you yourself rightly commented:
> 2. We also expect rationality, *which* is as **important** as all the other qualities.

The adjective *important* relates to the noun word *rationality* or *quality* in sentence 1 and to the relative pronoun *which* in sentence 2. The relative pronoun itself stands for  *rationality*, so in the end, we have an [adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective) modifying a noun.

If we used the [adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb) *"importantly"*, it would need a verb or an adjective to modify:

> We also expect rationality, and we expect it as **importantly** as all the other qualities.

But this sentence is invalid: one cannot expect something *importantly*. Some adverbs just don't combine with some verbs:

> I waited for her *very importantly* in the cafe, but she didn't come. (not okay)

One can expect something *eagerly*, for example, or *earnestly*:

> - We also expect rationality, and we expect it as **eagerly** as all the other qualities.
>     (or:)
> - We also expect rationality, and we expect it as **earnestly** as all the other qualities.

Comment: I just thought of another way of solving this - 1. We also expect rationality which is as important as all the other qualities. 2. We also expect rationality (which is) as important as all the other qualities ***Though I am not sure if in this case we omit "which is" it would be correct.*** 3. As important as all other qualities, we also expect rationality. Please tell me if I am right?

Comment: I guess you're right, the crux of the matter is that the adjective *important* modifies the noun *rationality*. In your remodelings, the relative pronoun *which* takes the role of *rationality* in a *relative clause* "which is as important as..". I guess your remodeling of the sentence is even closer to the original. If you omit "which is" in sentence 2, the meaning would change, and "important" would not work.

Answer (score 2):

By no means I can think of *importantly* there. Break the sentence in two parts.

> Other qualities are **important**...

...and so....

> Rationality should also be (equally) **important.**

The adverb *importantly* goes in sentence like this -

> We treat him as *importantly* as we treat our family member

This can be broken in two parts

> We treat him *importantly* ...

as

> We treat our family member *importantly*